# How to create a hidden navbar with HTML & Typescript that shows after you scroll?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone tell me how I can create a navbar which is hidden and only shows after you start scrolling the page (WITH TYPESCRIPT)?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark pb_navbar pb_scrolled-light w3-animate-right navlist-right  "  id="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Website</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler d-block d-sm-none"   (click)="toggleNavbar()" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#probootstrap-navbar" aria-controls="probootstrap-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span><i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i></span> </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  "  [ngClass]="{ 'show': navbarOpen }" id="onright">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#" >Home  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#service" >Service</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Here is a good [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_slide.asp "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_slide.asp")

Comment: Hi @IbramReda thanks for the link. Unfortunately I'm not good at Java script ... therfore I need the same code in Typescript :/

Comment: @Ferid_: Typescript is still Javascript. Pasting valid JS into a TS file will work, just you will get warnings (errors) from the checker.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav"  [ngClass]="{ 'show': navbarOpen }" id="onright">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#" >Home  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#service" >Service</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>        
  </ul>
</div>
<style>
.nav  {
top:-70px;
opacity:0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Hali, thanks for your Help. Unfortunately it didn't work that way. After I added the changes, the Navbar did not open at all.